# Regex - Combining positive and negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I am doing some replaces in some huge SSIS packages to reflect changes in table- and column names.

Some of the tabels have columnnames witch are identical to the tablenames and I need to match the columnname without matching the tablename.

So what i need is a way to match `MyName` in `[MyName]` but not in `[dbo].[MyName]`

`(?<=\[)(MyName)(?=\])` matches both, and I thought that `(?<!\[dbo\]\.)(?<=\[)(MyName)(?=\])` would do the trick, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include the opening square bracket in the first lookbehind:

```
(?<!\[dbo\]\.\[)(?<=\[)(MyName)(?=\])
```